# Drush hangs out on dl commerce_kickstart

Tags: commerce, drush, upgrading

in recent days new version of Commerce Kickstart 2 was introduced (v2.55).
I tried upgrading my current installation (v2.54) using drush:

```
drush --debug dl commerce_kickstart
```

unfortunately after this line:

```
Verifying signature for bzr version control engine. [3.27 sec, 42.21 MB]
Executing: bzr root profiles
```

I'm stuck with this , please give any some tips.
I'm using 7.4.0 drush version.

Comment: Checking the Commerce Kickstart version number, I can tell you are using Drupal 7. Maybe update your post with that info. Anyway, it's unlikely you'll get any help as the current version of Drush recommended for Drupal 8, is Drush 8.1.17 ... Drush 7.x is unsupported - ref bottom of http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ 
Read http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/ to get Drush 8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using drupal 7.60 with Commerce kickstart 2.55 now. I've figured it out. The problem was with the missing command line prompt asking to continue the installation in the current directory.
After debugging drush I noticed that i needed to type "y" than the process started to continue. Anyways it was very strange but finally it worked.